# Вырезаем часть post'a

Tags: php

При post запросе получается вот такой результат

```
/do/comment_all.php?url=/korabl_vikingov.html
```

Мне необходимо "вырезать" из этой ссылки вот такой кусок.

```
/do/comment_all.php?url=
```

Пробовал таким способом, не вышло.

```
$urlstr = $_POST['id'];
$word = '\/do\/comment_all.php?url=';
if(preg_match("/".$word."/i", $urlstr)) {
$urlstr = preg_replace("\/do\/comment_all.php?url=", "", $urlstr);
}
```

Comment: Если вы его заранее знаете, зачем вам его вырезать?  
Если это POST-запрос, то точно ли там вообще присутствуте GET-параметр и не идет ли перед ним другой GET-параметр?  
Точно ли в `$_POST['id']` должен оказаться URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, возможно, указанная ниже строка

```
/do/comment_all.php?url=/korabl_vikingov.html
```

хранится в переменной **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**.

Во-вторых, делать проверку на совпадение с помощью **preg_match** перед заменой этого же выражения с помощью **preg_replace** бессмысленно, поскольку если совпадения не будет, то и замены не будет.

В-третьих, у вас регулярка неправильная.
1) Нет обозначения начала и конца регулярного выражения
2) Не экранирован спецсимвол **?**

В результате ваша регулярка (если бы вы не забыли обозначить ее начало и конец) искала такое:

```
/do/comment_all.phurl=
/do/comment_all.phpurl=
```

**[Правильный вариант вашего регулярного выражения](http://regex101.com/r/bH0iG8/1)**:

```
@\/do\/comment_all\.php\?url=@i
```

Итого, если не менять ваш подход к решению, и исправить только явные ошибки, то решение таково:

```
$request = $_POST['id'];
$pattern = '@\/do\/comment_all\.php\?url=@i';
$urlstr = preg_replace($pattern, "", $request);
```

Или же, можно сделать иначе:

```
$urlstr = $_POST['id'];
$url_array = parse_url($urlstr);

# Теперь в $url_array у нас следующее:
# Array
# (
#     [path] => /do/comment_all.php
#     [query] => url=/korabl_vikingov.html
# )
parse_str($url_array['query'], $query_array);

# Теперь в $query_array у нас следующее: 
# Array
# (
#     [url] => /korabl_vikingov.html
# )

# Если идет обращение к /do/comment_all.php и есть get-параметр url, то:  
if ($url_array['path'] === '/do/comment_all.php' && isset($query_array['url'])) {
    # Присвоим его значение переменной
    $urlstr = $query_array['url']; 
    # Содержимое переменной: /korabl_vikingov.html
}
```